# Foreach logic issue with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, loops, foreach

I have I problem that I hope someone can help me with. I thought this code was right, but it will not work. Below is my code, it is a function for my CakePHP 2.2.2 site, the main aim of the code is to produce a menu system from database results. The problem is with my foreach loop, it will not loop. All $Key does is return the value of 2 (three records within the table at this time). So When I display / echo / debug $Menu, the only result I get is the last result stored within the database.

I know the SQL command is right, if that is debuged / echoed then all three results are displayed. The idea of this loop was to get it to count the results, so that I could run a check on a selected field. Where I am going wrong?

```
function MenuSystem() {
 $this->loadModel('Menu');

 $MenuSQL = $this->Menu->find('all', array('conditions' => array('active' => true)));

 foreach ($MenuSQL as $Key=>$Value) {

    $MenuSystem = $MenuSQL[$Key];
    $this->Menu = $MenuSystem;

 }

 }
```

Many Thanks,
Glenn.

UPDATE :::

Below is my function, now my foreach loop now works, don't know what I was doing wrong, but I know think its working. You can see the print_r command that I am using for testing, if I use that, then all links from my database are printed / echoed on the screen and all works. But if I try and call the $this->Menu from another controller, then only the last record is echoed on the screen. I have moved the $this->Menu outside of the foreach loop, but it made no difference, with it inside the loop or outside, it still only echoes the last record and not all three. So what I am doing wrong?

```
function MenuSystem() {
  $this->loadModel('Menu');
  $SiteBase = '/projects/cake/';
  $MenuSQL = $this->Menu->find('all', array('conditions' => array('active' => true)));

foreach ($MenuSQL as $key => $Value) {

    $MenuAccessLevel = $MenuSQL[$key]['Menu']['roles_id'];

    if ($MenuAccessLevel == 1) {
      $Path = $MenuSQL[$key]['Menu']['path'];
      $Title = $MenuSQL[$key]['Menu']['title'];
      $MenuSys = "<a href=\" " . $SiteBase . $Path . " \">" . $Title ."";
    } else {
       print ("Admin");
    }
    //print_r($MenuSys);
} //End of Foreach Loop 
   $this->Menu = $MenuSys;
} //End of function MenuSystem
```

Answer (score 3):

> So When I display / echo / debug $Menu, the only result I get is the last result stored within the database.

You're setting the value of `$this->Menu` within the foreach, so when the foreach is complete it will take the last value iterated over.

If you want to find the number of records matching a condition, try:

```
$menuCount = $this->Menu->find('count', array(
    'conditions'=>array('active'=>true)
));
$this->set(compact('menuCount'));
```

Edit: also, by setting the value of `$this->Menu` within the foreach, you're overwriting the  Menu model variable. This is not a good idea.

Edit2: to get the counts of rows as grouped by some value, try:

```
$this->Menu->virtualFields = array('count' => 'count(*)');
$counts = $this->Menu->find('all', array(
    'group'=>'Role',
    'fields'=>array('Role', 'count'),
));
```

This generates SQL to have the results grouped by the `Role` column. Returned fields are the name of the role, and the number of rows having that value.

If you wanted to do it with a foreach loop instead, it might look like:

```
$menus = $this->Menu->find('all', array('fields'=>array('id', 'Role')));
$counts = array('user'=>0, 'admin'=>0);
foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    $role = $menu['Menu']['Role'];
    $counts[$role] += 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for also correcting the syntax and using proper (cakephp) coding stadards :)

Comment: Sorry I don't think that will work for what I want it to do, count just gives you a total amount right? (I check it, play with it to see for myself). What my end goal is to check a field within the Menu table, called Roles, which will be set to user or admin. Therefore I don't need a total count, I need to loop around and check each record held within this table.

Comment: How will that work? Counts from what I know only 'count' the data, returning a number and not the data within the database. I need to be able to check each row and each field, one after the other. So for example, $MyRowData = $MenuSQL[ROWCOUNT]['Menu']['roles_id'] <- that would loop around so I can check each role with a statement. For example, If ($MyRowData == 1) { do this } else { do this }. I don't see how a count would work, its just counting the rows and not returning me my data, unless I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Glenn, I misinterpreted you. However, you can use the last code block in my answer and replace the two inner `foreach` lines with whatever you'd like to do to your records.

Comment: Glenn, `$this->Menu` holds your Menu model object, and you're overwriting it. What is the purpose of `$this->Menu = $MenuSys;`? If you're trying to write variables to the view, use `$this->set(...)`.

Comment: OK I think I get that :) Main aim is to build a global accessable Menu system, which I can then add to my default.cpt layout so that my site can see it. Many thanks for all your help Ben, I play about with this -set. Many Thanks,

Comment: I have used $this-set and not $this->Menu, see above, but it still doing that same thing. Only putting the last entry from the database into the var and not the all the results. I have even made sure by declaring the var I used to store the links in as an array. But still the only value I can display is the last entry and not all of them!! I am mad? Or is there something I am not doing....?

Comment: There's something about loops or variables you're missing. With your code, each time the foreach loops through, it sets `$MenuSys`. _previous_ values of `$MenuSys` are overwritten. Essentially you are saying _a=1; a=2; a=3_ and then being surprised that a is 3. I have an example here that may accomplish what you want: https://gist.github.com/5e8ac640dc0fb3cf6f7e, however I think you need to go back to some basic PHP tutorials before tackling a website.